# How to animate an element while using .before in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append .item element before .content element but it just simply removes .item from previous location and append before .content.

What i want is to use some animation that slowly remove .item element from its original position and appear slowly on its new position.. how can i do this?

```
$Item = $('.item');
$('.content').before($Item);
```

Regards.

Comment: @ Shoaib : will you able to make one jsfiddle demo link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9gGAT/2/ this what i am trying. i want to slowly hide item from upper area and show slowly before .content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:
[jsFiddl Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9gGAT/4/)

Comment: your code seems good to me as it uses some animation.. but it is not using .before method.. what i have to do in order to make it using .before instead of appendTo

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
$Item = $('.item');
$Item.fadeOut(1000, function() {
   $('.content').before($Item);
   $Item.fadeIn(1000);
}
```

The [`.fadeOut()` method](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) fades the element over the specified time (in milliseconds), and on completion calls the function which then moves the element and fades it back in.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9gGAT/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `hide` and `show` -methods of jquery to achieve a sliding effect. I'd also package the transition within it's own method so it can be reused, so you don't have to write the same code multiple times.

```
var smoothLikeSilk = function(mover, before) {
     $item = $(mover);
     $content = $(before);
   $item.hide('slow', function() {
     $content.before($item);
     $item.show('slow');
   });
}

$(function(){

  $('#btnMove').on('click',function(){
    smoothLikeSilk('.item', '.content');
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9gGAT/6/

Comment: Why not go the whole hog and write `smoothLikeSilk()` as a plugin? It'd be about the same amount of code...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function() {

    $('#btnMove').on('click', function() {
        $Item = $('.item').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.content').before($Item);
             $Item.fadeIn('slow');
        })

        });

    });​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BRLB3/)